# Раcпарсить строку в 3 массива

Tags: c++, c, arduino

В среде Arduino нужно обрабатывать строку чтобы получать алгоритм работы двигателя. Например из строки `"a15,s150,p10;a45,s200,p30;"` должно выйти 3 массива:

```
int stepperAngles[] = {15, 45};
int stepperSpeeds[] = {150, 200};
int stepperPauses[] = {10, 30};
```

Строка задается именно в таком формате. Количество состояний двигателя может меняться. Может стоит создать класс, например Frame в котором хранить 3 параметра для каждого состояния и уже из экземпляров класса делать массив? Если да, то как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Я давно не программировал на C++, и ни разу для Arduino, возможно у последнего есть какие-то ограничения, о которых я не знаю. Набросал что-то такое, используя векторы и стдшные строки:

```
vector<int> stepperAngles, stepperSpeeds, stepperPauses;

enum state {undefined, angle, speed, pause};

void parse(string str)
{
  state next = undefined;
  int num = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++)
  {
    if(str[i] == 'a')
      next = angle;

    else if(str[i] == 's')
      next = speed;

    else if(str[i] == 'p')
      next = pause;

    else if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') 
    {
      if(num == 0)
      {
        num += str[i] - '0';
        continue;
      }

      num *= 10;
      num += str[i] - '0';
    }

    else if(str[i] == ',')
    {
      if(next == angle)
        stepperAngles.push_back(num);

      else if(next == speed)
        stepperSpeeds.push_back(num);

      else if(next == pause)
        stepperPauses.push_back(num);
    }
  }
}
```

По моим представлениям, после минимальной доработки, должно работать.

Comment: `num` наверное надо обнулять для каждого следующего числа, также кроме `,` проверять ещё `;`

Comment: @Rennorb. Впереть STL в ардуину - негодное решение. Ограничения простые - оперативки - два килобайта. Процессор 20 MIPS (со скрипом).

Comment: @gbg контроллер esp8266

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не рекомендовал использовать данное решение в реально работающей программе. В нём нет никаких средств обработки ошибок. Что приведёт к самым непредсказуемым результатам во время эксплуатации программы.

IMHO, правильное решение - использовать библиотеку регулярных выражений (а Ваша строка - классическое регулярное выражение). Там всё разбирается, проверяется и контролируется...

```
man 3 regex
```

Comment: У автора все таки ардуино, что накладывает ограничение на память/быстродействие. Впрочем, если regex-ы укладываются в них, это самое простое и надежное решение.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian среда ардуино а контроллер esp8266 который довольно не слабый.

Answer (score 0):

Разработайте бинарный протокол и передавайте в контроллер информацию в том виде, в котором с ней нужно работать.

Заниматься парсингом строки - лишняя работа для контроллера, он и так слабенький, едва 20 MIPS делает.

Так как у вас там веб-сервер, отправляйте в запросе ваши массивы, закодированные в BASE64. Зачем устраивать себе лишнюю работу по парсингу?

Comment: на контроллере поднят Веб сервер. Строка на него отправляеться в GET запросе.

Comment: @AndrewRomanenko так отправьте нужные массивы, закодированные в base64. Еще проще.

Comment: Разница по нагрузке между парсингом base64 и кастомной строкой автора, по сравнению с наличием веб сервера, вряд ли будет заметна. А строка все таки читаема. Помните как все говорили что json это сакс, много лишних байтов. Но потом оказалось, что это круто отлаживать, а напряги компьютеров никого не волнуют. Т.е. я бы вообще отправлял в json (шучю)

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian У меня в контроллере скромная страничка в которой имеетьмя форма  с полем для ввода алгоритма. Я подумал что записать в ряд список параметров по шаблону это самый простой и дружественный для рядового юзера вариант. Или вы предлагае на уровне фронтэнда формировать правильный запрос применив немного js?

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение приходи на ум. Есть в нем одна проблема. Так как нельзя динамически задавать размер массива, пришлось задать его константой. Решить проблему можно двумя путями. Или использовать vector, или заранее определить максимальный размер массива.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
struct Frame{
    int a;
    int s;
    int p;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Frame &frame){
    is.ignore(1);   //a
    is >> frame.a;
    is.ignore(2);   //,s
    is >> frame.s;
    is.ignore(2);   //,p
    is >> frame.p;
    is.ignore(1);   //;

    return is;
}

int main(){
    const int size = 2;
    int arrA[size] = {0};
    int arrS[size] = {0};
    int arrP[size] = {0};
    std::istringstream is("a15,s150,p10;a45,s200,p30;");
    Frame frame;
    for(int i = 0; i < size && is >> frame; ++i){
        arrA[i] = frame.a;
        arrS[i] = frame.s;
        arrP[i] = frame.p;
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему нельзя задавать размер массива константой? Какие-то ограничения stl в ардуиновой sdk?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, можно задавать размер константой. Я говорил о том, что его нельзя менять динамически. И предложил два пути решения или взять вектор, или массив с запасом

Comment: Ну тогда второй вопрос почему нельзя менять динамически.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, отвечу вопросом на вопрос. А как изменить размер массива в стеке?

Comment: Все, понял, у вас не вектор, не внимательно прочитал.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, а можно компилируемый пример в котором вы меняете размер массива в стеке? На [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh), если не сложно. На сколько мне известно, это не возможно

Comment: Я же написал, что не внимательно прочитал, думал вы вектор используете.

Answer (score 0):

Спорное решение для микроконтроллеров с ограниченным RAM, но если все помещается, можно использовать возможности c++. С бустом было бы короче, но это уже совсем спорный вариант. Если памяти совсем впритык, и векторы/стримы ещё не используются в проекте, то лучше разбирать руками, как в ответе Rennorb.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct frame {
    int a, s, p;

    frame(const std::string& str) {
        istringstream sst(str);
        char c;
        sst >> skipws >> c >> a >> c >> c >> s >> c >> c >> p;          
    }
};

int main() {
    string s = " a15,s 150, p10 ;a45 ,s200,p30;";

    istringstream ss(s);
    ss >> skipws;

    vector<frame> vec;      
    string step;
    while (getline(ss, step, ';').good())
        vec.push_back(step);

    for (auto n: vec)
        cout << n.a << ", " << n.s << ", " << n.p << endl;
}
```

Действующий пример: https://repl.it/CiYZ/14